# How do I pick between elements using CSS selector

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium webdriver with java and lately I've been having problems with using the css selectors.
I have 3 mat-option elements that i need to pick between, I tried doing:

```
driver.findElement(By.CssSelector("mat-option[class='mat-option'(3)]")).click();
```

Yet it didn't pick anything...
I tried doing it like this because there is no other option known to me to pick between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `driver.findElements()` which returns a list and then click on the third item in that list:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.CssSelector("mat-option[class='mat-option']"));

elements.get(2).click(); // third item, index starts with 0
```